# WPS Office cannot access files on Virtualbox Shared Folder

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

I have an "Ubuntu-on-Windows10" Virtual-box set up.

I have installed WPS Office on Ubuntu 1804

I can access files on the shared folder using LibreOffice Calc, but when I tried to open an xls file on the Ubuntu guest using WPS Office, it cannot open the file.

```
Errors occur when WPS Spreadsheets opening this file.
Please try one of the following.
•Make sure you are permitted to access this file or drive
```

I have no problems using LibreOffice Calc to access.

How do I change the permission on the folder to allow access to WPS Office and other applications?

Tau

Comment: What are the actual athorisations on the file? Can you show how the shared folder appears in `df` output? In a terminal can you create a file in the shared folder (`touch`...) and if so can you create a file from scracth in WPS and save it to the shared folder?

Comment: No, WPS cannot read from the shared folder no can it see the file list.  If I upen up Files Manager, navigate to the sf_Data, chose a file and open with LibreOffice Calc if works fine.
If I choose WPS to open instead, the application fires up, and then display the permissions problem above.

Comment: You aren't answering my questions (`df` and actual access flags on the files (`stat` or `ls`). Some editors may deny opening an R/O file, while other will do but croak when you save.

Comment: Aplogies, I am a beginner in *nix.
I have used the "ls -l" command and it returns this 
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar  2 22:48 analytics_data_folder
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root   4096 Mar  6 10:41 datastore
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 4096 Mar  5 13:35 sf_Data


The shared folder is "sf_Data"

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your user id needs to belong to group `vboxsf` to read/write the shared directory.

In a terminal, enter `groups`, and check if the list contains `vboxsf`. If not, enter:

```
sudo usermod --append --groups vboxsf  {your id}
```

This will ask for your password. You have to logoff/logon the id for the group to be effective. Use `groups` again to check that it worked.

Comment: I added my userid to the vboxsf group earlier and that got Libreoffice to read/write to the vboxsf share.
But WPS Office and 7zip applications still cannot access the vboxsf share.

Comment: It is strange to me that Libreoffice can access vboxsf share (read and write) but WPS Office and 7zip cannot.

There are other things that stop my use of Ubuntu1804-on-Windows10, and using Anydesk to access the Ubuntu 1804 from remotely.
For one thing, Anydesk will accumulate the RAM and you have to clear down the Anydesk process by killing it for the RAM to clear down.